# what is wrong with this turtle code?

Tags: python

```
from turtle import *
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor(#0077AA)
t = turtle.Turtle()
#turtle
```

importing turtle

```
def square():
    for i in range(10):
        for j in range (4):
            t.pendown()
            t.forward(50)
            t.right(90)
        t.penup()
        t.forward(50)
```

defining a function

```
def multi_square():
    for k in range(10):
        square()
        t.right(90)
        t.forward(50)
        t.right(90)
        t.forward(500)
        t.right(180)
```

defining another function and calling a the first defined function in it

Comment: You will get better answers if you describe what your code is doing and how that's different from what you want it to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple errors in your code.

As iCodez points out, `#0077AA)` is a comment; you need quotes to make a string.

If you do `from turtle import *`, the classes and functions from `turtle` can only be accessed with unqualified names, like `Screen`; if you want to use qualified names like `turtle.Screen` you need `import turtle`.

You define two functions, but never call them, so your code won't do anything. You need to add a call to `multi_square()` at the end.

Your `multi_square` function draws one square, then moves all the way to the left edge of the screen and draws another (only partly-visible) one, then moves way off the edge of the screen and does nothing visible ever again. You need more sensible coordinates. Maybe you wanted to move 50, 50 instead of 50, 500?

I don't know whether this is a bug or a feature, but your `square` function draws the same square 10 times in a row. I'll assume you wanted that to watch the turtle running around.

Putting that all together:

```
import turtle
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor('#0077AA')
t = turtle.Turtle()

def square():
    for i in range(10):
        for j in range (4):
            t.pendown()
            t.forward(50)
            t.right(90)
            t.penup()
            t.forward(50)

def multi_square():
    for k in range(10):
        square()
        t.right(90)
        t.forward(50)
        t.right(90)
        t.forward(50)
        t.right(180)

multi_square()
```

[Here's the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exAZA.png)

Comment: heh, I was just typing this response :P

Answer (score 3):

You have to make the background color a string:

```
wn.bgcolor('#0077AA')
```

Otherwise, noting the `#`, Python thinks that that is a comment.